Nested Json Serialization Doesn't Work Event With explicitToJson: TRUE?
I am new to flutter and have been developing a small api that would pull data from a local mock database I created. The database has a nested Json within it, and no matter what I did, I can't get it to output anything other than "instance of 'Class'" instead of the actual Json within it. The code gets data from a Json that has mock data on an gym exercise and the sets and reps done
Here is the first model:
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:workout_card_api/src/models/sets.dart';

part 'exercise.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Exercise {
  Exercise({
    required this.exerciseId,
    required this.exerciseName,
    required this.exerciseType,
    required this.setList,
  });

  int exerciseId;
  String exerciseName;
  String exerciseType;
  List<Sets> setList;

  factory Exercise.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ExerciseFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ExerciseToJson(this);
}


Here is the second model:
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'sets.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Sets {
  Sets({required this.setId, required this.weightKg, required this.reps});

  int setId;
  int weightKg;
  int reps;

  factory Sets.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$SetsFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SetsToJson(this);
}

Here is the test code:
void main() {
  group('Sets', () {
    late Map<String, dynamic> json;

    setUp(() {
      json = {'setId': 1, 'weightKg': 30, 'reps': 15};
    });

    test('set object correct properties', () {
      final setData = Sets.fromJson(json);
      expect(setData.setId, 1);
      expect(setData.weightKg, 30);
      expect(setData.reps, 15);
    });
  });

  group('Exercise', () {
    late Map<String, dynamic> json;

    setUp(() {
      json = {
        'exerciseId': 2,
        'exerciseName': 'Bicep Curl',
        'exerciseType': 'Arms',
        'setList': [
          {'setId': 1, 'weightKg': 30, 'reps': 15},
          {'setId': 2, 'weightKg': 30, 'reps': 14},
          {'setId': 3, 'weightKg': 30, 'reps': 12}
        ]
      };
    });

    test('exercise object correct properties', () {
      final exerciseData = Exercise.fromJson(json);
      expect(exerciseData.exerciseId, 2);
      expect(exerciseData.exerciseName, 'Bicep Curl');
      expect(exerciseData.exerciseType, 'Arms');
      expect(exerciseData.setList, [
        {'setId': 1, 'weightKg': 30, 'reps': 15},
        {'setId': 2, 'weightKg': 30, 'reps': 14},
        {'setId': 3, 'weightKg': 30, 'reps': 12}
      ]);
    });
  });
}

The first part tests the sets model which works fine. The second part tests the exercise model which always outputs the following:
Expected: [
            {'setId': 1, 'weightKg': 30, 'reps': 15},
            {'setId': 2, 'weightKg': 30, 'reps': 14},
            {'setId': 3, 'weightKg': 30, 'reps': 12}
          ]
  Actual: [Instance of 'Sets', Instance of 'Sets', Instance of 'Sets']
   Which: at location [0] is <Instance of 'Sets'> which expected a map

I tried a lot of things like changing the type from Map<String, dynamic> to Map<String, Object> and creating a seperate build.yaml file. But no luck!

It works as intended. Only exerciseData is an object of type Exercise.

Error occurs because the expect function is comparing the setList of Exercise with a list of maps, but setList is actually a list of Sets objects.
Here's a solution:
One Way:
 test('exercise object correct properties', () {
      final exerciseData = Exercise.fromJson(json);
      expect(exerciseData.exerciseId, 2);
      expect(exerciseData.exerciseName, 'Bicep Curl');
      expect(exerciseData.exerciseType, 'Arms');

      expect(exerciseData.setList.length, 3);

      // Check the properties of each set
      expect(exerciseData.setList[0].setId, 1);
      expect(exerciseData.setList[0].weightKg, 30);
      expect(exerciseData.setList[0].reps, 15);

      expect(exerciseData.setList[1].setId, 2);
      expect(exerciseData.setList[1].weightKg, 30);
      expect(exerciseData.setList[1].reps, 14);

      expect(exerciseData.setList[2].setId, 3);
      expect(exerciseData.setList[2].weightKg, 30);
      expect(exerciseData.setList[2].reps, 12);
    });

Another Way:
 test('exercise object correct properties', () {
      final exerciseData = Exercise.fromJson(json);
      expect(exerciseData.exerciseId, 2);
      expect(exerciseData.exerciseName, 'Bicep Curl');
      expect(exerciseData.exerciseType, 'Arms');
      expect(exerciseData.setList, [
        Sets(setId: 1, weightKg: 30, reps: 15),
        Sets(setId: 2, weightKg: 30, reps: 14),
        Sets(setId: 3, weightKg: 30, reps: 12),
      ]);
    });


Thank you so much! It works now. I am new to programming so I completely missed it.
